# Change text of a cloned Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code:

```
($('<div/>', {id: "ErrorDiagnose"})).insertAfter('#DiagnosenTable');

 var Box = $('<div/>', {class: "panel panel-info"});
     Box.append($('<div/>', {class: "panel-body", style: "font-size:13px;padding:6px", text:"Back back to "}));

    $('#ErrorDiagnose').append(Box.clone());
    $('#ErrorDiagnose').append(Box.clone());
```

Basically it generates a new `div` and ads two Boxes to it.

My problem is that i dont know how i can change the text of the `panel-body` for a single Box.

Because now it generates the same boxes:

```
 Back back to 
 Back back to
```

But i would like that in one box there is another content:

```
 Back back to 
 Second Box
```

I hope you understand what i mean! Have a nice day! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of things.

```
var firstBox = $("#ErrorDiagnose").append(Box.clone());
var secondBox = $("#ErrorDiagnose").append(Box.clone());
```

Now you can do `firstBox.text("Hi!");`

Comment: But i want to change the text of the `panel-body`!