# How to clone a div and change the HTML data inside the cloned divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have spent a lot of time on this, and was not able to figure this out. I have a div called box which i want to clone. At the moment i am writing the code again and again in the `html` page for 10 boxes and putting their data inside. I now understand that it not the right way to do as the code is getting very long. what I wanted was the cloned boxes to have different data inside of them. For example the heading and data inside box 1 should be different to Box 2 and so on.

What I have tried: I have tried using `JQuery` by using the `.clone()` function inside a for loop. It worked out well, but I was not able to access the cloned elements. Please provide an example as I'm very new to this and have wasted a lot of time.

Main Goal: Eliminate rewriting the `HTML` code for the box (Eg. if i have 10 boxes), but have different data inside the 10 boxes. Eg Header, under class iconbar 2..  Please help me. Thank you!!!!

```html
    <div class="box" id="box">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
          <h3 id="Trailer_name"></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="img-container" id="image_container">
          <iframe
            style="width: 15vw; height: 18vh"
            frameborder="0"
            src="map.php"
          ></iframe>
        </div>

        <form method="post">
          <p>
            <button type="button" class="button3">
              <ion-icon class="icon2" name="contrast-outline"></ion-icon>

              LIGHTS
            </button>

            <a href=""><button class="button">ON</button></a>
          </p>
        </form>

        <form method="post">
          <p>
            <a href=""><button type="button" class="button2">OFF</button></a>
          </p>
        </form>

        <div class="icon-bar">
          <a class="active" href="#">Solar PV</a>
          <a class="active" href="#">Battery </a>
          <a class="active" href="#">Power</a>
          <a class="active" href="#">Video</a>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-bar2">
          <a class="active" href="#"> 48 </a>
          <a class="active" href="#">250 V</a>
          <a class="active" href="#">1.5KW</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can't help you without your code. Here is an answer about [changing some text in a cloned element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129123/change-text-of-a-cloned-box).

Comment: hey @LouysPatriceBessette i have updated with the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery loop and keep your data in array. now when loop run your data will populated in div

```js
var things = ["Solar PV", "Battery","Power","Video"];

for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
  $("<div>"+things[i]+"</div>").appendTo("#inserts");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inserts">
        
</div>
```